# WebView в проекте Windows Phone на C#, как получить конечный адрес после перехода?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, mobile-development

Есть проект Windows Phone на нем есть компонент `WebView`. По нажатию кнопки переходит на определенный ресурс. 
Есть необходимость узнать что :

1. Загрузка закончена полностью, то есть и все редиректы и тд
   закончились.
2. Получить конечный адрес.

Пытался после окончания брать ( просто в самый конец) из `WebView.Source`, но там хранится тот который был указан для Navigate.
Гуглить пытался, но видно нужно меня ткнуть носом, сам найти не смог.

Например: http://vk.cc/snBwO в WebView загрузился как и должен был google но `WebView.Source` равен `vk.cc/snBwO`, а я хотел бы видеть `https://google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подпишитесь на событие [`NavigationCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted.aspx), нужный URL будет в аргументах события ([`WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewnavigationcompletedeventargs.uri.aspx)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, большое. В силу своего не знания, я забывал указывать <WebView NavigationCompleted="eventhandler"/>. В итоге написанная функция ничего не принимала, а я сидел и гадал где же проблема.

Comment: @Kind_predatoR не за что!